# Should only Real Numbers be used when finding the limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

Let's say we have the function $y = \sqrt{x(5-x)}$

When you plot the function you can see that the domain range of the function is at $x=5$ so if you try and approach the limit from the left-hand side at $x = 5$ you can do it but if you try and approach the limit from the right-hand side at $x = 5$ you're out of the domain of the function and so the limit doesn't exist.

We know that the limit as $x$ approaches $5$ from the left-hand side is $0$

`limit(sqrt(x * (5 - x)), x, 5, dir='-')`

$0$

But when happens if I approach it from the right-hand side?

`limit(sqrt(x * (5 - x)), x, 5, dir='+')`

$0$

My symbolic mathematics library is insisting that the limit is 0 even though we know that can't be since any number above $5$ such as $5.0001$ is outside the range of the function.

The reason for this is if I substitute in a number very close to $5.0$ such as $5.001$ I end up getting $\sqrt{5.001(5.001 - 5)}$

$5.001 * (5-0.001) = -0.005001$

`sqrt(-0.005001)`

$0.0707177488329486$

This is approaching $0$ the closer you get to $5$, which is why I'm getting the output I'm getting.

So all in all is using imaginary numbers in this context **legal** or **illegal** when finding the limit of a function?

Comment: If you are learning Analysis I now I suggest you not consider this kind of problem. It is settled mainly in Complex Analysis. The point $z=5$ is a branch point of $\sqrt{z(5-z)}$.

Comment: Assuming Real Analysis, rather than Complex Analysis, the domain of the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x(x-5)}$ is $x \leq 0$ or $x \geq 5.$  The domain of this of this combined union is the set $D$.  By definition, when (for example), you are taking the **2-way** limit of the function, as $x$ approaches $5$, from **either** side (i.e. $x < 5$ or $x > 5$), it is understood, that all elements $x$ that are not in the domain $D$ of the function are to be ignored.  In this context, the 2-way limit, as $x$ approaches $5$ of $f(x)$ does in fact exist.